# ValueError: RSA key format is not supported

Tags: python, google-app-engine

trying to use big query on google app engine python. I am trying to achieve this using a [this client library](https://github.com/tylertreat/BigQuery-Python) . I have imported every necessary library and somehow running the snippet below

```
from bigquery import get_client

# BigQuery project id as listed in the Google Developers Console.
project_id = 'project_id'

# Service account email address as listed in the Google Developers Console.
service_account = 'my_id_123@developer.gserviceaccount.com'

# PKCS12 or PEM key provided by Google.
key = 'key.pem'

client = get_client(project_id, service_account=service_account,
                    private_key_file=key, readonly=True)
```

and still get the error:

```
    2015-10-26 19:08:37 Running command: "['C:\\Python27\\pythonw.exe', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\google_appengine\\dev_appserver.py', '--skip_sdk_update_check=yes', '--port=19090', '--admin_port=9010', 'C:\\Users\\CrowdStar\\workspace\\AppEngineThinkStudio\\TrafficTestCase']"
INFO     2015-10-26 19:08:39,540 devappserver2.py:726] Skipping SDK update check.
INFO     2015-10-26 19:08:39,634 api_server.py:172] Starting API server at: http://localhost:61626
INFO     2015-10-26 19:08:39,634 dispatcher.py:186] Starting module "default" running at: http://localhost:19090
INFO     2015-10-26 19:08:39,651 admin_server.py:118] Starting admin server at: http://localhost:9010
INFO     2015-10-26 18:08:44,361 discovery.py:240] URL being requested: GET https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/bigquery/v2/rest?userIp=%3A%3A1

INFO     2015-10-26 18:08:44,361 client.py:563] Attempting refresh to obtain initial access_token

ERROR    2015-10-26 18:08:44,365 webapp2.py:1528] RSA key format is not supported

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.3\webapp2.py", line 1511, in __call__

    rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.3\webapp2.py", line 1505, in __call__

    rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.3\webapp2.py", line 1253, in default_dispatcher

    return route.handler_adapter(request, response)

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.3\webapp2.py", line 1077, in __call__

    return handler.dispatch()

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.3\webapp2.py", line 547, in dispatch

    return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.3\webapp2.py", line 545, in dispatch

    return method(*args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\CrowdStar\workspace\AppEngineThinkStudio\TrafficTestCase\main.py", line 72, in get

    private_key_file=key, readonly=True)

  File "C:\Users\CrowdStar\workspace\AppEngineThinkStudio\TrafficTestCase\bigquery\client.py", line 83, in get_client

    readonly=readonly)

  File "C:\Users\CrowdStar\workspace\AppEngineThinkStudio\TrafficTestCase\bigquery\client.py", line 101, in _get_bq_service

    service = build('bigquery', 'v2', http=http)

  File "C:\Users\CrowdStar\workspace\AppEngineThinkStudio\TrafficTestCase\oauth2client\util.py", line 142, in positional_wrapper

    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\CrowdStar\workspace\AppEngineThinkStudio\TrafficTestCase\googleapiclient\discovery.py", line 196, in build

    cache)

  File "C:\Users\CrowdStar\workspace\AppEngineThinkStudio\TrafficTestCase\googleapiclient\discovery.py", line 242, in _retrieve_discovery_doc

    resp, content = http.request(actual_url)

  File "C:\Users\CrowdStar\workspace\AppEngineThinkStudio\TrafficTestCase\oauth2client\client.py", line 565, in new_request

    self._refresh(request_orig)

  File "C:\Users\CrowdStar\workspace\AppEngineThinkStudio\TrafficTestCase\oauth2client\client.py", line 835, in _refresh

    self._do_refresh_request(http_request)

  File "C:\Users\CrowdStar\workspace\AppEngineThinkStudio\TrafficTestCase\oauth2client\client.py", line 862, in _do_refresh_request

    body = self._generate_refresh_request_body()

  File "C:\Users\CrowdStar\workspace\AppEngineThinkStudio\TrafficTestCase\oauth2client\client.py", line 1541, in _generate_refresh_request_body

    assertion = self._generate_assertion()

  File "C:\Users\CrowdStar\workspace\AppEngineThinkStudio\TrafficTestCase\oauth2client\client.py", line 1670, in _generate_assertion

    private_key, self.private_key_password), payload)

  File "C:\Users\CrowdStar\workspace\AppEngineThinkStudio\TrafficTestCase\oauth2client\_pycrypto_crypt.py", line 121, in from_string

    pkey = RSA.importKey(parsed_pem_key)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pycrypto-2.6.1-py2.7-win32.egg\Crypto\PublicKey\RSA.py", line 665, in importKey

    return self._importKeyDER(der)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pycrypto-2.6.1-py2.7-win32.egg\Crypto\PublicKey\RSA.py", line 588, in _importKeyDER

    raise ValueError("RSA key format is not supported")

ValueError: RSA key format is not supported

ERROR    2015-10-26 18:08:44,372 wsgi.py:279] 

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\runtime\wsgi.py", line 267, in Handle

    result = handler(dict(self._environ), self._StartResponse)

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.3\webapp2.py", line 1519, in __call__

    response = self._internal_error(e)

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.3\webapp2.py", line 1511, in __call__

    rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.3\webapp2.py", line 1505, in __call__

    rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.3\webapp2.py", line 1253, in default_dispatcher

    return route.handler_adapter(request, response)

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.3\webapp2.py", line 1077, in __call__

    return handler.dispatch()

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.3\webapp2.py", line 547, in dispatch

    return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\webapp2-2.3\webapp2.py", line 545, in dispatch

    return method(*args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\CrowdStar\workspace\AppEngineThinkStudio\TrafficTestCase\main.py", line 72, in get

    private_key_file=key, readonly=True)

  File "C:\Users\CrowdStar\workspace\AppEngineThinkStudio\TrafficTestCase\bigquery\client.py", line 83, in get_client

    readonly=readonly)

  File "C:\Users\CrowdStar\workspace\AppEngineThinkStudio\TrafficTestCase\bigquery\client.py", line 101, in _get_bq_service

    service = build('bigquery', 'v2', http=http)

  File "C:\Users\CrowdStar\workspace\AppEngineThinkStudio\TrafficTestCase\oauth2client\util.py", line 142, in positional_wrapper

    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\CrowdStar\workspace\AppEngineThinkStudio\TrafficTestCase\googleapiclient\discovery.py", line 196, in build

    cache)

  File "C:\Users\CrowdStar\workspace\AppEngineThinkStudio\TrafficTestCase\googleapiclient\discovery.py", line 242, in _retrieve_discovery_doc

    resp, content = http.request(actual_url)

  File "C:\Users\CrowdStar\workspace\AppEngineThinkStudio\TrafficTestCase\oauth2client\client.py", line 565, in new_request

    self._refresh(request_orig)

  File "C:\Users\CrowdStar\workspace\AppEngineThinkStudio\TrafficTestCase\oauth2client\client.py", line 835, in _refresh

    self._do_refresh_request(http_request)

  File "C:\Users\CrowdStar\workspace\AppEngineThinkStudio\TrafficTestCase\oauth2client\client.py", line 862, in _do_refresh_request

    body = self._generate_refresh_request_body()

  File "C:\Users\CrowdStar\workspace\AppEngineThinkStudio\TrafficTestCase\oauth2client\client.py", line 1541, in _generate_refresh_request_body

    assertion = self._generate_assertion()

  File "C:\Users\CrowdStar\workspace\AppEngineThinkStudio\TrafficTestCase\oauth2client\client.py", line 1670, in _generate_assertion

    private_key, self.private_key_password), payload)

  File "C:\Users\CrowdStar\workspace\AppEngineThinkStudio\TrafficTestCase\oauth2client\_pycrypto_crypt.py", line 121, in from_string

    pkey = RSA.importKey(parsed_pem_key)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pycrypto-2.6.1-py2.7-win32.egg\Crypto\PublicKey\RSA.py", line 665, in importKey

    return self._importKeyDER(der)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pycrypto-2.6.1-py2.7-win32.egg\Crypto\PublicKey\RSA.py", line 588, in _importKeyDER

    raise ValueError("RSA key format is not supported")

ValueError: RSA key format is not supported

INFO     2015-10-26 19:08:44,404 module.py:737] default: "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

Comment: Where did you get the key?

Comment: from my google developer console.

Comment: Is it possible that the version of PyCrypto you're using is bad? It's being sourced not from a lib folder local to your project, but from your system's version in `site-packages`. Ultimately, the exception is thrown from there, so... perhaps try to use pip to install pyCrypto into the app's directory and use `sys.path` to add the installed version of the module it to your python path.

Comment: If all of that is nonsense and doesn't work/help, you can check out [this issue on the github issue tracker for the BigQuery client you're using](https://github.com/tylertreat/BigQuery-Python/issues/43), which seems highly-related.